# Make Wordpress User Name be the Company Name when Registering (not the default 'first name' last name' email address')

Tags: login, username

Is it possible to make WordPress User Name the Company Name instead when user registers on a site.

So the Company Name Field on the form is used as the key field upon registration? (Not first name, last name or email address).

Comment: I don't think there is a company name field by default at least: just username and email. How is your form set up? I expect there will be a hook you can use, yes, but that'll depend on what you've actually got.

Comment: And company name isn't necessarily unique: how would you handle duplicates?